# How to bulk save in Fast API using sqlalchemy add_all

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, python-typing

I'm trying bulk add patients to the DB, but I'm running into an error.
The goal is to read the data from the body of the request, truncate the data in the table and add the new data.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**code**

*schemas.py*

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class PatientBase(BaseModel):
    ticket_id: str
    patient_name: Optional[str] = None



class PatientInDb(PatientBase):
    patient_id : str
    institute :str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

*crud.py*

```
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

def create_patients(db: Session, patients: List[schemas.PatientInDb] ):
    num_of_deleted_rows = db.query(models.Patient).delete()

    db.add_all(patients)
    db.commit()
    return db.query(models.Patient).count()
```

*patients.py*

```
@router.post("/patients")
async def post_patients(
    patients : List[schemas.PatientInDb],
    db: Session = Depends(get_db),
    
):
    patients_count = crud.create_patients(db, patients)
    return {
        "message":f"New {patients_count} patients created."
    }
```

**error**

```
  File ".\app\api\v1\patients.py", line 45, in post_patients
    patients_count = crud.create_patients(db, patients)
  File ".\app\crud.py", line 13, in create_patients
    db.add_all(patients)
  File "c:\users\convergytics\miniconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2016, in add_all
    for instance in instances:
  File "c:\users\convergytics\miniconda3\envs\test\lib\typing.py", line 682, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "c:\users\convergytics\miniconda3\envs\test\lib\typing.py", line 1107, in __getitem__
    params = tuple(_type_check(p, msg) for p in params)
  File "c:\users\convergytics\miniconda3\envs\test\lib\typing.py", line 1107, in <genexpr>
    params = tuple(_type_check(p, msg) for p in params)
  File "c:\users\convergytics\miniconda3\envs\test\lib\typing.py", line 374, in _type_check
    raise TypeError(msg + " Got %.100r." % (arg,))
TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got 0.
```

Comment: Deleting all patients inside a request without any `where` clauses sounds like a bad idea. Best case, you're gonna have a lot of dead garbage rows in SQL and a slow endpoint for continuously removing and adding the same records. Worst case, you'll have a problem with timing issues if two users call the endpoint at roughly the same time, but they don't know about each others patients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file "patients.py"

Change:

```
"patients = List[schemas.PatientInDb]"
```

to

```
"patients: List[schemas.PatientInDb]"
```

Reason, " = " is for assigning a default value, " : " is for referencing the type.

Comment: Hey, sorry. I corrected that mistake. it works fine now if I iterate over the list and upload, one element at a time by parsing each as sqlalchemy model.

Is there any better way to do it?. (maybe by avoiding the for loop)

Answer (score 0):

You got this answer on discord as well, but you're saving pydantic models instead of sqlalchemy models.

Comment: We can save using a pydantic model when the other fields in the table are nullable. Anyway, The reason for the error listed above happened because of the unrealistic assignment in the parameter.